# Magento automatic redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I am having this problem...

I need to get some bugs out of an online magento shop, so I did copy all files to localhost and I did import the database.

> When I try to view the front-end, magento automatically redirect's to
>   the online store. I did search in the database & files, and no results
>   of an redirect. I also did check htaccess files, but I didn't find
>   anything to do with an redirect.

Has anybody experienced this problem to?

Thanx in addvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change some database settings.

In `core_config_data` update `web/unsecure/base_url` + `web/secure/base_url` to your localhost url.

Comment: Thanx! Now I get an error request on Magento, probably local.xml

Comment: @JannyBomans Make sure you turn developer mode on in index.php and configure `errors/local.xml` to let you see more information about those errors.